# How to retrieve cadence workflow result through CLI or Java Client

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

How to query workflow end result through CLI or Java Client given a workflow-id

Comment: What is the use case? Usually it is a bad idea to query for the workflow result from the externa client.

Comment: Currently, the external client(customer) triggers an asynchronous HTTP request and then polls for the result through a monitor URL. We are planning to replace the asynchronous operation (which is basically moving customer content across cloud regions) with Cadence workflow. So, we may be having a thin wrapper service around cadence and when client triggers asynchronous HTTP request, we will execute the workflow and when client polls for the result we need to check the workflow progress and then return the result if the workflow is executed. Is it a bad idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for a workflow result synchronously given WorkflowID using Java Client:

```
WorkflowStub client = workflowClient.newWorkflowStub(
       workflowId, Optional.empty(), Optoinal.of("workflowType"));

ResultClass result = client.getResult(<ResultClass>.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to check whether the workflow is still executing and then try fetching the result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If it is still executing then this call is going to block. Do you want something else?

Comment: I'm looking for something like client.isWorkflowRunning() which returns true if workflow is in progress.

Comment: Try getResult(timeout, ....) method with 0 timeout.